# How to read a large stream and compare counts?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a stream that is reading data like this:

```
id | color | shade | 5
1 | red | light
2 | green | dark
3 | blue | light
4 | grey | light
```

I need to read the first line, get the integer (5) in this case, then count the remaining lines, and find out (`true/false`) whether the count matches. In this case 5 doesn't match 4 so it would be `false`.

I'm doing this right now which works ok n some data but starts to error out and give me OOM  on large streams (over 1M records). This is what I'm doing

```
class FirstLine (totalCount: Int)
class ColorLine (id: Int, name: String, shade: String)
class Everything(firstLine: firstLine, List[ColorLine] colors)

    val headerResult: Future[FirstLine] =
      myRawStr(ctx)
        .take(1)
        .via(framing("\n"))
        .map(_.utf8String)
        .map(_.trim)
        .map(s => FirstLineParser(s))
        .collect {
          case Right(fl) => fl
        }
        .runWith(Sink.head)

    val restResult: Future[immutable.Seq[ColorLine]] =
      myRawStr(ctx)
        .drop(1)
        .via(framing("\n"))
        .map(_.utf8String)
        .map(_.trim)
        .map(s => ColorLineParser(s))
        .collect {
          case Right(color) => color
        }
        .runWith(Sink.seq)

    def validateAndError(everyThing: Everything): Future[List[MyError]] =
      validate(everyThing) match {
        case Left(errors: Seq[MyError]) =>
          val persisted: Future[ValidatedError] = ctx.asScala.self ? (
              (ref: ActorRef[ValidatedError]) =>
                PersistError(someId,Some(ref)))
          persisted.map(_ => errors)

        case Right(_) =>
          Future.successful(Nil)
      }

    for {
      header <- headerResult
      rest <- restResult
      res <- validateAndError(Everything(header, rest)
    } yield res
```

**Question**

Is there a way to improve the efficiency of the above code so that it works for over 1M records?

Comment: Your problem is when you have a lot of records, you cannot keep them all in memory (Reading everything into `myRawStr` itself may cause OOM, depending on how big your file is).
What you need is a streaming solution which reads a chunk of the input, process them, and then read the next chunk. This means you can process arbitrarily large input with constant memory use. Some options include [monix](https://monix.io/docs/3x/#monix-reactive), [fs2](https://fs2.io/guide.html) and [akka-streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/).

Comment: [this blog post](https://softwaremill.com/reactive-streams-in-scala-comparing-akka-streams-and-monix-part-1/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to not collect the `restResult` as a `Seq[ColorLine]` and instead just produce a count of color-lines as the result:

```
type Count = Long

val zeroCount : Count = 0L

val countColorLine : (Count, ColorLine) => Count = 
  (count, _) => count + 1

val restResultCount: Future[Count] =
  myRawStr(ctx)
    .drop(1)
    .via(framing("\n"))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .map(_.trim)
    .map(s => ColorLineParser(s))
    .collect {
      case Right(color) => color
    }
    .runFold(zeroCount)(countColorLine)
```